# How to run specific method from another activity with an intent

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have a radio button activity with 5 choices for the game. It's a quiz game, so the user can choose to play until he or she makes one error, two errors, tree, four and five errors. My question is....is it better to make 5 activities and 5 classes, so I can call intent of each activity when user check that radio button, or, is better to make one activity, for all five choices and depending on what user chose, to count until 1,2,3,4 or 5 errors? I know how do the first option, but I don't know how to do the second one. Here my choice activity:

```
public class Izbor extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener{

    MediaPlayer buttonBack;
    RadioButton rbDeset,rbDvadeset,rbNeogranicenoTriGreske,rbNeogranicenoJednaGreska,rbNeogranicenoPetGresaka;
    Button dNazad, dStart;
    RadioGroup rGrupa;
    TextView tv1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.izbor);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {

        Typeface dugmad = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Bebas.ttf");
        Typeface pitanjeVrh = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Lobster.ttf");


        rbDeset = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rbDvadeset = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        rbNeogranicenoJednaGreska = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        rbNeogranicenoTriGreske = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio4);
        rbNeogranicenoPetGresaka = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio5);
        dNazad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNazad);
        dStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
        rGrupa = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        buttonBack = MediaPlayer.create(Izbor.this, R.raw.back);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        dNazad.setTypeface(dugmad);
        dStart.setTypeface(dugmad);
        rbDeset.setTypeface(dugmad);
        rbDvadeset.setTypeface(dugmad);
        rbNeogranicenoPetGresaka.setTypeface(dugmad);
        rbNeogranicenoJednaGreska.setTypeface(dugmad);
        rbNeogranicenoTriGreske.setTypeface(dugmad);
        tv1.setTypeface(pitanjeVrh);


        rGrupa.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        rbDeset.setOnClickListener(this);
        rbDvadeset.setOnClickListener(this);
        rbNeogranicenoJednaGreska.setOnClickListener(this);
        rbNeogranicenoTriGreske.setOnClickListener(this);
        rbNeogranicenoPetGresaka.setOnClickListener(this);
        dStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(rbDeset.isChecked()){
                    startActivity(new Intent("rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.KVIZ"));
                }else if(rbDvadeset.isChecked()){
                    startActivity(new Intent("rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.DVADESETPITANJA"));  
                    }else if(rbNeogranicenoJednaGreska.isChecked()){
                        startActivity(new Intent("rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.TRIDESETPITANJA"));
                    }else if(rbNeogranicenoPetGresaka.isChecked()){
                        startActivity(new Intent("rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.NEOGRANICENOPETGRESAKA"));

                }

            }
        });


        dNazad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonBack.start();
                finish();

            }
        });
    }

    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

And here is one activity where a user can play until 5 mistakes:

```
public class NeogranicenoPetGresaka extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button bIzlazIzKviza, bOdgovor1, bOdgovor2, bOdgovor3, bOdgovor4;
    TextView question, netacniOdg, score;
    int counter = 0;
    int brojacPogresnihOdgovora = 0;
    int brojacTacnihOdgovora = 0;

    Runnable mLaunchTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            nextQuestion();
        }
     };
    Runnable mLaunchTaskFinish = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            finish();
         }
      };


    private class Answer {
        public Answer(String opt, boolean correct) {
            option = opt;
            isCorrect = correct;
        }

        String option;
        boolean isCorrect;
    }
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Answer ans = (Answer) v.getTag();
            if (ans.isCorrect) {
                brojacTacnihOdgovora++;
                Intent i = new Intent("rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.TACANODGOVOR");
                startActivity(i);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,1200);
            }
        else{
            brojacPogresnihOdgovora++;
            Intent i = new Intent("rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.POGRESANODGOVOR");
            startActivity(i);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,2200);
            }
        }
    };


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.neograniceno5gresaka);

        Typeface dugmad = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Bebas.ttf");
        Typeface pitanje = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Lobster.ttf");
        bIzlazIzKviza = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIzlazIzKvizaN);
        netacniOdg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBrojPitanjaN);
        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPitanjeN);
        bOdgovor1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgovorN1);
        bOdgovor2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgovorN2);
        bOdgovor3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgovorN3);
        bOdgovor4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgovorN4);
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSkor2N);
        bOdgovor1.setTypeface(dugmad);
        bOdgovor2.setTypeface(dugmad);
        bOdgovor3.setTypeface(dugmad);
        bOdgovor4.setTypeface(dugmad);
        bIzlazIzKviza.setTypeface(dugmad);
        netacniOdg.setTypeface(dugmad);
        question.setTypeface(pitanje);
        score.setTypeface(dugmad);

        nextQuestion(); //startuje prvo pitanje!

    }

        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPause();
        }

    public void nextQuestion() {

        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{    //Pokusava da otvori db

            mDbHelper.open();  //baza otvorena

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData();

            List<Answer> labels = new ArrayList<Answer>();

            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(3), false));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(4), false));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(5), false));

            Collections.shuffle(labels);

            if(brojacPogresnihOdgovora < 5){


        question.setText(c.getString(1));

        bOdgovor1.setText(labels.get(0).option);
        bOdgovor1.setTag(labels.get(0));
        bOdgovor1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor2.setText(labels.get(1).option);
        bOdgovor2.setTag(labels.get(1));
        bOdgovor2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor3.setText(labels.get(2).option);
        bOdgovor3.setTag(labels.get(2));
        bOdgovor3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor4.setText(labels.get(3).option);
        bOdgovor4.setTag(labels.get(3));
        bOdgovor4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        //reset your next question and all four options here
        netacniOdg.setText("" + brojacPogresnihOdgovora);
        score.setText("Score: " + brojacTacnihOdgovora);
            }
            else{
                Intent i = new Intent("rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.REZULTAT");
                startActivity(i);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTaskFinish,4000);
            }
        }
        finally{    // kada zavrsi sa koriscenjem baze podataka, zatvara db
            mDbHelper.close();
        }

    bIzlazIzKviza.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();   
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want? A working code sample to achieve the second option?

Comment: First, I would like to if the second option is better or not. If it is, I would like sample code. I don't want to make it from scratch cause I have a lot of things going on in my activity so far, so I wouldn't like to lose that. If it's the same, I don't mind making all five activities like I did with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the choice is just a small setting to the same game I see absolutely no reason to create one class/activity for each choice, it would be sheer madness.

As for the settings part, just create a numeric only input field that accepts any amount of "errors" ( why not ? ).
OnClick get the input from this field, save the value to the intent extras and start the game with the intent. In the onCreate of the game read the intent extras and get the number of "tries"/"errors".

Comment: No, I need to keep my radio buttons, for some other reasons. How can I call an activity with the radio button, but some specific method in that activity?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I tried with onNewIntent, but I can only call one method, and I need at least 3. Here's the code in my choice activity with radio buttons(group):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                if(rbDeset.isChecked()){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Izbor.this, Kviz.class);
                    intent.putExtra("myMethod", "nextQuestion");
                    startActivity(intent);
```

And here's my quiz activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        if(intent.getStringExtra("methodName").equals("nextQuestion")){
              nextQuestion();
        }

              }
```

I tried with ELSE IF but it didn't work. My methods are named: nextQuestion(), nextQuestion2() and nextQuestion3(). These are pretty much same methods only with different counters (one for 10 questions, one for 20 and one for 30). Maybe I don't need 3 methods to do this but honestly I don't know other way to do that.